# How to find the probability function and distribution function of Y=|X-3|

Tags: probability-distributions

If the random variable $X$ has probability function

```
x          0       1       2       3       4       5

p(x)     0.03    0.06    0.13    0.20    0.31    0.27
```

,specify the probability function, distribution function, mean and variance of 
$Y=|X-3|$

Comment: What have you tried? Add that to your question (not in a comment). Further welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at both links [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and for formatting [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: First of all calculate $y=|x-3|$ for all $x=0,1,2,3,4,5$, For instance for $x=0$ we have $y=|0-3|=|-3|=3$

Comment: As per above the values of y only range between 3,2,1,0,1,2 and if we take the probability of x at each of these points then it doesn't add upto 1.

Comment: What "above" you mean? What were your calculations and results?

Comment: Here are the results:      x 0 1 2 3 4 5  y 3 2 1 0 1 2   p(y) .20 .13 .06 .03 .06 .13  When I add these then the probability of these doesn't add up to 1. I am not sure if I am solving it right! Apologies for the poor format as I am very new to this.

Comment: @user507124 Your values for p(y) are hard to interprete. I have posted a hint. If you have any further questions you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $x=1$ then $y=2$, If $x=5$ then $y=2$. Therefore for $y=2$ we get $p(y)=0.06+0.27=0.33$

If $x=2$ then $y=1$, If $x=4$ then $y=1$. Therefore for $y=1$ we get $p(y)=0.13+0.31=0.44$

Then the table for $y$ looks like

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline y&0&1&2&3  \\ \hline p(y)& ? &0.44&0.33&? \\ \hline \end{array}$$

It is comprehensible? Can you finish the table?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @user507124 You´re welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark, if you want.